# PHP Save Form to Image or PDF with Styling

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I'm rewriting an app that I created last year. For whatever reason I cannot find the methods I used to save my form with my bootstrap styling, as an image or PDF. It was almost like taking a screenshot of the page, and what was shown. So far, what I've found strips the CSS.

My apologies if there is an answer here somewhere, but I've been searching for hours. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these classes to convert HTML into PDF:

1-[DOM PDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

2-[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Hope these help you

Comment: Thank you very much! I think DOMPDF was what I tried last time. It works well for the most part, but it seems to have an actual issue with the bootstrap css (running issue since 2014). Actually, I do believe TCPDF was what I used for this project last year, and had no issue with the image save. One way to find out. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, about the closest answer possible. mPDF which I found later was suppose to support styling, but didn't really seem to do such. These seem to be the best possibilities, but ending up having to restyle everything anyways, since nothing likes bootstrap css (that I could see).