# Download page as pdf file

Tags: javascript, php, html, file

I am creating some kind of document generator. I send data through form, it is loaded in next page. Now i need a button, to download this document as pdf file.
Is there any way to do this? I have seen few similar topics, but they usualy direct people to online converters, which do not help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php this may help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679170/php-save-form-to-image-or-pdf-with-styling/35680056#35680056 this may help you

Comment: [look in to this jspdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery) this will help you. it only uses javascript

Answer (score 4):

I did something like that in the past in more ways.
If you want to avoid online converters, then I think you should choose between using a PHP library or (if you have access at the server) a dedicated software.

There are some good PHP library aimed in PDF creation like:
- TCPDF (www.tcpdf.org)
- FPDF (www.fpdf.org)

If you have server access I suggest you using:
- wkhtmltopdf (www.wkhtmltopdf.org)
But in this case you need to first create your document as a static html file including all your styles and stuff into.
Then you can convert that html documento into a pdf simply by a commmand:

wkhtmltopdf /path/to/document.html /path/to/generated.pdf

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which is a good open-source solution to generate PDF and supports many types of PDF layouts. This solution can be implemented in PHP.

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

To generate PDF from HTML using PHP, you can use [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/).

You can also use [PHP's built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 1):

I use mpdf. Documention: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=452
You can add your own css file, header, footer, etc.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("MPDF54/mpdf.php");

$i = 0;
if(isset($_POST['apstiprinat'])){ 
    $patiess = $_POST['apstiprinat'];
    if($patiess == "apstiprinat"){ 
        function prieksmeti_izdruka(){
            $pr = ""; 
            $i = 0; 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT prieksmets FROM prieksmeti"); 
            $pr .= "<table>";
            $pr .= "<tr><td><b>Nr.</b></td><td><b>Prieksmeta nosaukums</b></td></tr>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $i++;
                    $pr .= "<tr><td>{$i}.</td><td>{$row['prieksmets']}</td></tr>";
                }
            $pr .= "</table>";
            return $pr;
        }

        $html = "".prieksmeti_izdruka()."";
        $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');
        $mpdf->SetHeader('Mācību priekšmeti {DATE D-M-Y}');
        //$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
        $mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('noformejums.css'); 
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); 
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output();
        exit;
    }
} 
else { echo "Izdrukas apstiprinājums nav saņemts!;(";}
 ?>
```

Minus of this libary is that you need duplicated your code. This libary accept one parameter. In this case `$pr` where I add all string.

And another minus is that, if you need pdf where is very very long table (about 100 pages), then it very long generate this document.

Answer (score 1):

i think that you need to look for a library that can spare you all the repeated work and duplicate codes like TCPDF or FPDF. in the same time you will learn some intersting skills that will help you in your future works.